# Ubuntu 20.04 Static Route Issue with Netplan. No route to host error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

I am upgrading from Ubuntu 16.04 to 20.04 and I am giving Netplan a try. I have two interfaces. I want certain traffic to go out on the second interface (ens06). This is kind of working. I see traffic for 199.111.222.333 going out the second interface to the internet when I run a tcpdump, however; no connection is made and I receive a "no route to host" error. I am sure it is some simple issue in the config, but I cannot seem to pinpoint it.

My config:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    ens5:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: false
      match:
        macaddress: '02:98:b5:d1:f5:0c'
      set-name: ens5
    ens6:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: [100.64.1.77/32]
      routes:
      - to: 199.111.222.333/32
        via: 0.0.0.0
        scope: link
  version: 2
```

My routes

```
default via 10.47.8.1 dev ens5 proto dhcp src 10.47.8.7 metric 100
10.47.8.0/24 dev ens5 proto kernel scope link src 10.47.8.7
10.47.8.1 dev ens5 proto dhcp scope link src 10.47.8.7 metric 100
199.111.222.333 dev ens6 proto static scope link
```

Comment: Can you ping 199.111.222.333 from your machine?

Comment: No. ICMP is not configured to respond on the other side though. I know it is up though because I have and old server that is able to hit that IP without a problem.

Comment: Is 199.111.222.333 linked locally? I guess I'm surprised that you can talk to that address in a completely different subnet with no gateway.

Comment: I am actually on AWS. I have a single VPC with two CIDR ranges, two subnets for the VPC, and two interfaces. The 199.X.X.X address is actually on the other side of a transit gateway and not associated directly with this network. My route table in AWS pushes all traffic to 199.X.X.X to the transit gateway. I was trying to keep AWS out of the details since I know that piece is working fine.

Comment: I removed one interface and it works fine so I know the issue is with how traffic is being passed between the interfaces.